# Questions about split() and for each loops

Tags: python

I am given a file that looks like this with many more lines that I am giving.

```
4
5 r begin
20 wr Dark tunnel
```

I have created a class to handle each part of the line that I am trying to split using the split() operation. To do this I am splitting based off of spaces, but for example in the 3rd line that says "Dark tunnel" I am splitting this apart as well, but need it to read as "Dark tunnel".

The other question that I have is with the for each loop, I want to perform the same operation on each line, except for the first line that is just the number 4, where I need to multiply that by itself minus 1 (4 * (4-1))

I created a class that takes the split line and assigns each part that is split. I have also made the for each loop, but as of now it performs the same operation on every line including the first one.

```
class point:
    def __init__(self, val, route, title):
        self.value = val
        self.route = route
        self.title = title
```

Want to properly split the lines, and perform a different operation on the first than the rest.

Comment: `str.split(None,3)` should avoid to split the last item

Answer (score 1):

For split, you could do:

```
parts = s.split()
val, route, title = parts[0], parts[1], ' '.join(parts[2:])
```

For the for loop, you could do:

```
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if index == 0:
        result = int(line)*(int(line)-1)
    else:
        # do something else
```

All together:

```
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if index == 0:
        result = int(line)*(int(line)-1)
    else:
        parts = line.split()
        val, route, title = parts[0], parts[1], ' '.join(parts[2:])
        p = point(val, route, title)
```